# How to animate an approximation of a sunflare?

Tags: modifiers

I have no idea what sort of modifiers to use.

I would imagine some matter that's fluidy and produces a light with some magnetism physics on the globe.

I don't want to be exact in terms of physics, I'm going more for a symbolic representation. Fancy Kurzgesagt, if you get my point. See this moment for reference: https://youtu.be/oHHSSJDJ4oo?t=11

---

Edit: I drew my own reference, 2d representation of a 3d blow of plasma. It looks a bit like a water drop, dripping off, but with a shine and physics of plasma.
[image]

If you know a relevant YT tut, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be done in Geometry Nodes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Next step would be to animate the effect by e.g. scaling the curves…

Comment: that's interesting, can you put the file online?

Comment: @lexfriedman it's not a technical problem for me to share the setup, however I think BSE is a teaching/learning website, not an asset sharing website… As a rule of thumb I share setups when I think other active users ('teachers') may want to investigate or reuse them in other posts, and I don't want to share a more localized solution for 'learners', as I think they benefit more from recreating the setups themselves.

Comment: thanks. I wanted to ply around with it, because it's not really what I'm after. Recreating it just for play doesn't seem to be reasonable ATM.

Comment: I'm marking this as solved, tho I didn't really get my answer. My bad, I guess -- added the crucial info too late.

Comment: @lexfriedman I think what I've made was quite similar to the Kurzgesagt video you linked as a reference? Plus "I'm going more for a symbolic representation."

Comment: Yeah, that representation is now attached as a hand-drawn picture. I'm getting into physics and geometry nodes. I'll try and figure this out.